# [Hibernate]Merge transient object with childrens

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I've some probleme with merge. My update method works in this way:

```
void update(Parent parent) {
    evict(parent);
    merge(parent);
}
```

My classes:

```
Parent {

  Long id;

  List<Children> childrens;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity =ChildrenImpl.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="PARENT")
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
  List<Children> getChildrens(){...}

  @Id
  Long getId() {...}

}



Children{

  Parent parent;

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ParentImpl.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT", nullable = false)
  Parent getParent(){...}

}
```

When i create a new Parent(transient) object and add new childrens and trying updated(evict & merge)  then logs show me this after flush hibernate session:

```
INSERT PARENT //everythings here is ok.

INSERT CHILDREN // but without parent id(id=null)
```

Order is good but children doesn't have parent id in insert. Everything works fine when Parent is persisted in database, then childrens always have a good id.

Any ideas what should I do to get id from transient object(from persisted is ok).

Regards
KZ.

Comment: did you try saving the transient instance first via session.saveOrUpdate() so that an id gets attached to the entity? did you check in a debugger that your entity has an id when the insert for the child object is performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get an id from a transient object, by definition a transient object does not have an id.

why are you doing a merge if you create a new object?  When you create a new object, you should save it.  If you change the values of an existing object, you should update it.  You should be merging only if an object that was persistent becomes detached, and you need to reattach it.

Comment: Take the case of a very complicated object graph then. Say I export it into an XML, make a bunch of changes, then import it back in. It may be extremely difficult and hard to maintain if you have to get the existing persistent object then compare it to the old one and all its cascades and dependencies and update it. Instead, it'd be nice to create a transient object with the new one, compare the new to the old, add IDs to the new transient object, merge, and save. This is what I'd like to do, but are you saying that's not possible?

Comment: how to distinguish between new object with notNull Id to detached object ? there is no way I guess. So then it is ok to do merge having new object with set id. We may have this logic if our Entities are immutable - we have to create new object then.